# find links in plain text and convert them to hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

My requirement is if I received the message if it is having any hyperlinks in message (like [www.gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com) etc) Then It has to show as Links like Anchor tag links with with underline and blue color(as on  tag)

my JavaScript code is
**.js**

```
//var postMessage = MessageGet($("#PrivateConversation #ConversationTextarea"));
    var urlRegex = /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/g;
    var detectURL = postmsg.match(urlRegex);
    //console.log(detectURL);

    var resultPost = '<a href= "' + detectURL + '" role="link" > ' + postmsg + '</a>';

    console.log(postmsg);
```

From the above I am getting the text only if it is having hyperlinks also it is showing in text format

Comment: did you wrongly log the `postmsg` variable while you are modifying the `resultPost` variable?

Comment: No I need Only text right that's why I have taken the postmsg.  and just I declared the variable for that that's it

Comment: it is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve: do you want to convert the links in a hyperlink format? or you want to strip them out?

Comment: Yes,I want to convert the links in Hyperlink format ,can you please help me

Comment: Your question is _"How to make the links in message **if** the sending message is having the links"_ You need an `if` in your code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I embed a snippet which should solve your problem: your code was correct, but it had some problems in the console log and in replacing the links with the right content.

```js
function transformHyperlinks() {
const postmsg = document.getElementById("start").value;

const urlRegex = /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/g;
const detectURL = postmsg.match(urlRegex);

let resultPost = postmsg

detectURL.forEach(url => {
  resultPost = resultPost.replace(url, '<a href= "' + url + '" role="link" > ' + url.trim() + '</a>')
}) 

document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = resultPost;
}
```

```html
<h2>Old text</h2>
<textarea id="start">test https://facebook.com https://www.google.com test</textarea>

<button onclick=transformHyperlinks()>Transform Hyperlinks</button>

<h2>New text</h2>
<div id="end"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @aaandri98 But I need the text and If the text is having the links then the links only has to show in the hyperlinks text should be as it is

Comment: i updated the snippet, in order to show that I achived already what you want - unless I did not understand your question

Answer (score 0):

```
function transformHyperlinks() {
  const postmsg = document.getElementById("start").value;

  if (!postmsg) {
    console.error("The element with ID 'start' was not found.");
    return;
  }

  const urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g;
  const detectURL = postmsg.match(urlRegex);

  let resultPost = postmsg;

  if (detectURL) {
    detectURL.forEach(url => {
      resultPost = resultPost.replace(url, `<a href="${url}" role="link">${url}</a>`);
    });
  }

  const endEl = document.getElementById("end");
  if (!endEl) {
    console.error("The element with ID 'end' was not found.");
    return;
  }

  endEl.innerHTML = resultPost;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if the URL wasn't found:

```js
function transformHyperlinks() {
const postmsg = document.getElementById("start").value;

const urlRegex = /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/g;

const resultPost = postmsg.replace(urlRegex, function (_, contents) {
        return `<a href="${contents.trim()}" role="link">${contents.trim()}</a>`;
    });

document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = resultPost;
}
```

```html
<h2>Old text</h2>
<textarea id="start">test https://facebook.com https://www.google.com test</textarea>

<button onclick=transformHyperlinks()>Transform Hyperlinks</button>

<h2>New text</h2>
<div id="end"></div>
```